# I'm getting empty string '' or 'undefined' from .val()-function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

What I'm trying to do is to catch the value of the `input` with the class `statisPrice-0` or written in the code like:

`statisPrice-" . $i . "`

as the number will be increasing `0,1,2,3,4...` I will need later to do some math calculations with this value.

I tried several ways to catch the value of the `input`, but I'm getting an empty string or `undefined`. I have read here and all the answers didn't helped me to fix my issue.

```
echo "<input type='number' name='qtty-" . $i . "' class='col-md-6' min='" . $good['Ratio'] . "' step='" . $good['Ratio'] . "' value='" . $good['Ratio'] . "'>";
echo "<div class='col-md-3'>";
    echo "<div class='col-md-12'><strong>Цена в лв.</strong></div>";
    // this is the input:
    echo "<input type='hidden' class='statisPrice-" . $i . "' val='" . number_format((float)$good['PriceOut2'] * $good['Ratio'], 3, '.', '') . "'>";
    echo "<div class='col-md-12 price-" . $i . "'>" . number_format((float)$good['PriceOut2'] * $good['Ratio'], 3, '.', '') . "</div>";
echo "</div>";
```

and my jquery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//change the price
    var thisIsIt = $(this);
     $("input[name*='qtty']").change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        var getName = $(this).attr("name");
        var getNumber = getName.substr(5, 10);
        // this is the code where im trying to catch the input and i tryed several ways and noone of them worked :(
        var price = thisIsIt.find(".statisPrice-" + getNumber).val();
        alert(".statisPrice-" + getNumber);
        alert(price); //outputs empty string ""
        alert(val);
        thisIsIt.find(".price-" + getNumber).text(val * price);
    });
});
```

I dont get it why it can't take the valuw of the `hidden input` and make the calculation -> `val * price`

I will be thankful if someone can tell me where I'm mistaking.

Comment: `<input>`s need a `value` attrib, not a `val` attrib

Comment: Urgh, all that string concatenation. Just `echo` the dynamic parts, eg `<input name="qtty-<?= $i ?>"...`

Comment: thank you very much!!!!! of course this is the problem, but i was thinking the jquery its not wokring and was searching the problem somewhere else u can write this as an answer so i can mark it as answered! thank you again. now its working fine!

Comment: @Pnil, u r right it should be like u said, but this is closed in one big php block and i think it will be more code to put it in a clear html mixed with php. im newbie so i dont know what are the best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in @dandavis comment, your attribute on your `<input>` element needs to be `value` instead of `val`.

```
<input ... value=".." />
```

Answer (score 1):

you should be using

```
$( "input[name^='qtty']" )
```

instead of using alert use console.log

or even better place a debugger at problem location

in your case before  `var price = $(".statisPrice-" + getNumber).val();`

and check what values are available at run time.

Comment: `name^='qtty'` and `name*='qtty'` will both match an element with `name="qtty-n"`